# How to Iterating array data in a table one by one

Tags: templates, dynamic, mustache, dynamic-tables

I have a dynamic table, am try to iterate a array object one by one in table.Am using Mustache template to iterate it.

```
<tbody>

    <tr>
       <td>{{ip}}</td>  
       **<td>{{#action-allow}}{{.}}{{/action-allow}}</td>**
        </tr>
</tbody>
```

[image]

It should be first Row - Deny only ,Second row- Deny, and third row-Allow etc.
But am getting all together. How can i make it one by one.
I need exactly like below picture. 
how to achieve this ? 
[image]

The template what getting is  **"action-allow":["Deny","Deny","Allow","Deny","Deny"] "**

Answer (score 1):

try the following. Change action-allow to action only. 
Here is live demo http://jsfiddle.net/26dAy/2/

```
var data= '{"action":["Deny","Deny","Allow","Deny","Deny"]}';
var arr=$.parseJSON(data);
var arr2=arr.action;
 $.each(arr2, function(i, item) {
        alert(arr2[i]);
    });
```

Comment: How to work it in template ? {"action":["Deny","Deny","Allow","Deny","Deny"]} am getting this value in template

Comment: I just want to iterate it in template